# Impact on performance by using external jars in servlets

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am using Eclipse WTP for a project. It requires few libraries to be used. Few are small in size and few are larger. My question is, what happens when we use external jars in servlets ? If I am importing a heavy-weight library in a Servlet, does it impacts webpage load time ?

Or Java just compiles my program including libraries to give results. I understand heavy-weight jar will take time to load once even on my local machine, but I can manage them to be initiated only once (by creating a separate class and initiate static variables and use them from other classes). But seems like, this can't be done in Servlets and every time a page is loaded, servlet has to load all those heavy jars.

Is it good to use Guava and Solrj in Servlets ? Do they slow down (asking because I feel Solrj is slowing down webpage load time) ?

Answer (score 0):

Including a jar in-and-of itself does not slow down servlet run time. However, using a particular tool/class/functionality in a jar may slow down the servlet, depending on what you are trying to do.

I recommend using a profiler to analyze your code and actually determine what it causing the slowdown. [Here's a quote from Martin Fowler's Refactoring](http://amzn.com/0201485672):

> I had speculated with various members of the team (Kent and Martin deny participating in the speculation) on what was likely wrong with code we knew very well. We had even sketched some designs for improvements without first measuring what was going on.
>
> We were completely wrong. Aside from having a really interesting conversation, we were doing no good at all.
>
> The lesson is: Even if you know exactly what is going on in your system, measure performance, don't speculate. You'll learn something, and nine times out of ten, it won't be that you were right!

Comment: oh yes, by including external jars, I meant using methods that consume time in delivering webpage. That means use of jars is going to slow down webpage loading speed.

Comment: @akshayb Right, but some jars might actually speed up your code. It depends on the situation. That's why you should always profile before guessing.

Comment: We can initiate objects of libraries through listeners ?