# Servlet Listners And Loading External Jars Performance

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Yesterday I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660715/impact-on-performance-by-using-external-jars-in-servlets/23660774?noredirect=1#comment36343687_23660774) on if loading/importing classes/& creating objects from external libraries in servlets cause any performance issue ? Answer I got is may or may not but if library size is big and if we are initiating memory intensive/time consuming jar in Servlet, it is surely going to slow down page load time.

Further question is : is it possible that if we use Listners, (initiate objects from time consuming libs on Tomcat startup, and use them in servlets wherever needed) we can save time taken on every pageload  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you will only save time in the first or initial pageloads.

Once the [Classloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) builds up the library and its instances generated by your application, further pageloads would be barelly affected.